# what should I have to use in boost geometry function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, boost-geometry

Now i'm analyzing polygon example in boost geometry

[http://geometrylibrary.geodan.nl/03_*polygon*_example_8cpp-example.html](http://geometrylibrary.geodan.nl/03__polygon__example_8cpp-example.html)

After draw a few lines, if I want to get cross point between polygon border line and normal lines, what function should I use??

[Click to See a sample image what i want](https://picasaweb.google.com/113906158804476060636/2011331#5590115627563187522)

I want to know those red circle point coordinate. I don't know that a way of combination of line points i inserted and the polygon

Answer (score 0):

Would the function documented [here](http://geometrylibrary.geodan.nl/group__overlay.html#gb1e5ee8de503557bb689c7c259446b9b) (`get_intersection_points`) help?  You could intersect your line segment with the shapes you want to check.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
That function was not included in my boost library. So, I have searched it, and added it from the function document web page. (get_intersection_points.hpp, intersection_point.hpp) But, it shows some errors. Did I forget something? I just installed boost library windows version 1.46.1. But there are not a few function files.

Comment: Sunddenly, 16 errors are occurred in iterator, value_type and get_intersection_points.hpp. It was working good, before add 2 new files about intersection point hpp files. Do I have to do something to use it?